# Concatenate multiple strings with HTTPResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two variable strings. How do i pass the result of both the strings with my HTTPResponseMessage

```
var masterInfo = entities.Empmaster.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == EmployeeID)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();

string masterDepartment = entities.Departments.Where(d = DepartmentID = 
                                                  MasterInfo.DepartmentId)
                                                  .select(d => d.Name)
                                                  .FirstOrDefault();

if (masterInfo == null)
{
   return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Info");
}
else
{
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, masterInfo);
}
```

Whenever i try to concatenate masterDepartment with masterInfo

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, masterInfo + 
masterDepartment);
```

I don't get any error but a single output stating System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EmpMaster_260ECB16225F4E5E0232BA72326492E9BADA61D68BE4DCEF48D365296F69975F Human Resource. 
Though somehow i get the result of masterDepartment i.e Human Resource. But not the result of masterInfo.
If i just pass one variable as shown in first example i get the output as expected.

Comment: do you want to merge `NotFound` and `OK` result to single response?

Comment: @ershoaib: No brother. Why will i do that? I just want to show the contents of both my variables masterInfo and masterDepartment as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood,

You want to return both of `masterInfo` and `masterDepartment` with `OK` response

Then try below code

```
if (masterInfo == null)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Info");
}
else
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { MasterInfo = masterInfo, MasterDepartment = masterDepartment });

    //OR

    //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { masterInfo, masterDepartment });
}
```

Try once may it help you

**Edit:**

Here we create an `Anonymous Type` with keyword `new` means simply create new type without defining them

You can learn more about `Anonymous Type` from [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-anonymous-type)

Comment: @Tausif Khan, view my newly posted answer may it help you

Comment: Ah fantastic!! that helped bro.

Comment: Yes sure I'll update you soon...now m out of my office

Comment: Ok.. No problem

Comment: @Tausif Khan, please view edited section in answer and visit the link provided in answer .
and vote up, and accept my answer of your previous asked question 'Encryption issue in Web API` if its really help

Comment: i need to connect to you personally. I have some API doubts, n you're really helpull bro. I can't chat with you personally here because of my low reputation. Please reply. I am Stuck with my API project.

Comment: where can i text you bro? facebook, insta anywhere?

Comment: Sorry friend, stackoverflow does not premit us to contact presonally. You have to post  your futher  questions here. After post you can ping me, then iI'll deifinitely help you as i can,  Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither masterInfo nor masterDepartment is a string, it's an instance of the entity you're querying. If you're looking to concatenate a member of those entity instances, you'd do something like the following.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
  masterInfo.SomeStringField + masterDepartment.SomeOtherStringField);
```

Comment: Thanks i agree, but i don't get the result. someStringField and SomeOtherStringField doesn't work for me. Could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?